Yii2 Style Push Array
I have a php array defnied with Yii2 style definitions like this. Below is not a standard value being pushed to an array, but rather a Yii2 style definition, as such it seems a standard array_push method does not work.
$cart = array('2'=>array('disabled' => true));

Above works just fine, however when I try this, I get all sorts of errors.
$cart = array();
array_push($cart, '2'=>array('disabled' => true));

How can I get the array_push to work?
